# newPlot() function is not working with DOM element in Plotly.js as running from typescript file

Tags: javascript, typescript, plotly, plotly.js

I have a typescript project. I want to draw a histogram for an array of numbers. But it is throwing me an error when I am trying to draw [image]it on a new window and a DOM element.

```js
 public showHistogram(arrOfValues: number[]){
         arrOfValues = [1,2,3,4,5,4,1,2,3,6,5,11];
        let trace = [{
            x: arrOfValues,
            type: 'histogram' as Plotly.PlotType,
          }];

        var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=1000,height=1000");
        myWindow.document.write("<div id='histo'><p>Histogram!!!</p></div>");
        var element = document.getElementById('histo');
        //if (element != null){Plotly.newPlot('histo', trace)};
        Plotly.newPlot(element,trace);
        return 1; 
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the element from your new window instead of the current window:

```
var element = myWindow.document.getElementById('histo');
```